# rsync recursively and exclude content of specific directory, not the directory

Tags: linux, command-line, rsync

I have a directory tree like this :

```
dir1/
   file11
   file12
   file13
   ...
   file1548216479524594
dir2/
   file21
   file22
dir3/
   dir31/
      file311
      file312
   dir32/
      file321
```

I would like to `rsync` entire directory tree but without content of directory dir1.

If I use the basic `rsync` command :

```
rsync --progress -v -ar --delete --exclude="dir1/*" src/ dst/<br>
```

It works. But if I use -n to make a dry run before execute, it lasts very long because dir1 contains a lot file (I do not know why during the dry-run it lists all files, even those excluded).

If I use `--exclude="dir1/"`, the dry-run is fast but I don't have my directory tree.

How can I do a rsync dry run fast (avoiding recursively dir1 files which are very numerous.) with my entire directory tree excluding all content of dir1 ?

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: The question is : how can I do a rsync dry run fast (avoiding recursively dir1 files which are very numerous.) with my entire directory tree excluding all content of dir1 ?

Comment: then please add the question to your "Question", so people don't have to scan the comments to find out what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of rsync, you can use the -F option and put a file ".rsync-filter" in the directory src, containing:

```
- dir1/***
```

That seemed to work for me.  I'm assuming that your hierarchy above is all under "src/".